# create a bitmap file with ofstream have a strange output

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, ofstream

i am trying to open a bitmap file in c++, change it and then create another bitmap file. the problem is when i try to output a bitmap file with ofstream, even without changing any byte of file, it has a strange output.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream fin ("6.bmp", std::ios::binary);
    ofstream fout ("output.bmp");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1920*1080*3 + 54; i++)
        fout.put(fin.get());
}
```

1920 * 1080 is size of picture and *3 for RED, GREEN, BLUE. i know that a bitmap file have a 54-byte header, so i think there are exactly 1920*1080*3 + 54 bytes in 6.bmp;

when the input is : [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHGl8.png)

then i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN1Wf.png) for output.

(i resized both pictures for uploading them but they both are 1920*1080)

i compiled this code with g++ in windows 8.1. and i don't want to use bitmap library.

Comment: *and i don't want to use bitmap library* -- You actually thought that resizing a bitmap can be done with a one line `fout` loop?

Comment: Did you check the size of the file with `DIR` because your assumption about the length is probably wrong - due to padding and other things.

Comment: What are actual sizes of input and output files? STL streams is not a good thing for binary files, it often traits `\0` and `\n` in a different way you want.

Comment: @ilotXXI as i said input size is about 1.97MB while output size is about 5.93MB.

Comment: @Mark input size is 2,074,678 bytes while output size is 6,221,378. i don't know why that happen?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i did not resized it with this code. this code simply does nothing but input image bytes and just output them again in another file.

Comment: @iambb5445 If that's all the code does, then why even bring up resizing images?  If it's just a binary file copy, the question should have just stated "binary file copy".

Comment: With Windows, `fout` also must be opened in binary mode, otherwise a 0x0d byte will be auto-inserted before every 0x0a byte, corrupting the output file.

Comment: @Paul i was just saying that images i uploaded are resized versions of real input and output - because of maximum size limit for uploading. not really important, i just wanted to say input and output files are 1920*1080 even though the files i uploaded have other sizes.

Comment: @Christopher thanks a lot! that was the problem! i don't know why i have thought fout does not need that. thanks again.

Comment: @Christopher will you please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Windows, fout also must be opened in binary mode, otherwise a 0x0d byte will be auto-inserted before every 0x0a byte, corrupting the output file.